# How can I assign struts 2 value to java script global variable?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery-ui, jsp, struts2

I have following struts2 variable

```
<s:set id="var" var="i" value="%{#i+1}"/>
```

How I can assign this value to global variable paramCount ?

I have tried following

```
var paramCount = '<s:property value="i"/>';
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: More details? Code snippet maybe? What do you want to happen? Just a single assignment?

Comment: yes Mark....I just want to get the value of "i" assigned to paramCount

Answer (score 0):

See this example:

```
<s:set name="personName" value="person.name"/>
Hello, <s:property value="#personName"/>. How are you?
```

So in your case it would be something like this :

```
<s:set var="i" value="%{#i+1}"/> 
<s:property value="#i"/>
```

More explanation [here](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/components/Set.html).

Comment: hi etr, How can I get the value of "i" in java script?

Comment: I have tried var paramCount = '<s:property value="%{#i}"/>';..but does n 't work.. I have updated my code as you mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a variable and initialize it.

```
<s:set var="i" value="0"/>
```

then you can reference it in JSP to increment a value by one.

```
<s:set var="i" value="%{#i+1}"/>
```

Now, to render javascript with the value of `i`, you should use quotes if you want a string value or without quotes to use as numeric value. I guess that you need a second case, because you variable name looks like a numeric. Then you have code

```
var paramCount = <s:property value="#i"/>;
```